# Notification Access in KitKat

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, settings, notifications

Can someone tell me where the Notification Access is placed in KitKat.
In JellyBean it used to be under Settings -> Security.

Comment: What is "the Notification Access"? What phone do you have? Different phones have different settings.

Answer (score 2):

It's still in Settings > Security on my Nexus 5.

This option will only appear if there are apps that register as being able to read notifications. (I have verified this by uninstalling the apps that appeared in the list, and the option was no longer there)

[image]

Comment: I can't see it, either on emulator running KitKat or my real device Samsung Galaxy S4

Comment: It's not there on mine either, but I don't think I have any apps installed that have permission to access notifications anyway.  Maybe the setting doesn't appear if there'd be nothing to configure?

Comment: No that's not the reason. I am developing an app which needs permission to access notifications to work correctly. With that app installed on my device I still cant see the setting.

Comment: It would appear that your app is not registering that it wants to read notifications correctly - see my edit.

Comment: Have to double check that @bmdixon, but I think my app should be configurated correctly as it shows upp in Notification Acces on Jelly Bean

Answer (score 2):

On my Galaxy S5 KitKat, Notification Access is under Sounds and Notifications

Answer (score 0):

I used to get there via apps like Pushbullet

Comment: Seems very strange if you need to use a app to access it, are you sure this is the only way to access this?

Comment: I think it's like "hidden" or something.

Answer (score 0):

I found it on Samsung Galaxy Tab 4 as follows.

Settings -> General -> Security -> DEVICE ADMINISTRATION -> Notification access -> allow for your app.

Answer (score 0):

On my Alcatel pixi3 (4) (don't laugh) it's under advanced network settings. You get to this via the 'hard' menu button from the WiFi network selection screen.